# Multiple buttons in the same page submit to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have multiple button in the same page like 50 maybe more to submit a single value to Ajax wordpress way. They look like this:

```
<input id="1-57977357564a7" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Done"/>
<input id="2-57977357564a7" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Done"/>
<input id="3-57977357564a9" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Done"/>
// And so on, more buttons
```

Each button should update on row in some database table.
It should call `update_completed_todos()` using Ajax

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_completed_todos', 'update_completed_todos');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_completed_todos', 'update_completed_todos' );
function update_completed_todos() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'todos';
    $id = '';// Need to pass the id here some how
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM " . $table_name .  " WHERE id = '" .$id."'");
    if (count ($result) > 0) {
        $wpdb->update( 
            $table_name, 
            array(  
                'complete'   =>  '10', 
            ),
            array( 'id' => $id )
        );
    }
}
```

I need to pass the `id` some how to this function. 
What should I write in Ajax to pass the `id`? 
And how I can make each button target this Ajax? 
As Ajax may not pass `id` instead of a value, what should I do to pass any value to Ajax here? 
The Ajax should be something like:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "<?php echo esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ?>",
     type: "POST",// I am not sure
     data: // Something I don't know here
     //may be more here     
 });
```

Comment: use onclick="update_completed_todos('your param here')" and instead of type="submit" use type="button"

Comment: @Abbas I think onclick= doesn't work with php function. This doesn't answer the ajax part of my question. `Actually this doesn't related to my question at all as I mentioned clearly it's ajax issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="1-57977357564a7" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Done" onclick="ajax($(this));return false;"/>
<input id="2-57977357564a7" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Done" onclick="ajax($(this));return false;"/>
<input id="3-57977357564a9" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Done" onclick="ajax($(this));return false;"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function ajax($this) {
    var id = $this.attr("id");


    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "your address",
        dataType: "your response type",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    var_dump($_POST["id"]);
    exit;
}
```

of course you must change dataType and url to your data.

**The wordpress way**

**Javascript:**

```
function ajax($this) {//If you got error "Function ajax is not defined" declare this before document ready
    var id = $this.attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ?>",
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
            action: "update_completed_todos",// call the php function 
            id: id // store id
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_completed_todos', 'update_completed_todos');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_completed_todos', 'update_completed_todos' );
function update_completed_todos() {

    $id = $_POST['id'];// store id from ajax
    //do something with this id
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, and it worked with wordpress ajax very well. Thanks.

Comment: dataType will be `"text"` and url will be `"<?php echo esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ?>"`